# AttributeError: 'Accounts' object has no attribute 'deploy'

Tags: python, blockchain, solidity, brownie

The .deploy() function is working for FundMe.sol contract but not for MockV3Interface.sol Contract.

Here's my deploy.py code below:

```
from brownie import FundMe, MockV3Aggregator, accounts, config, network
from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_account


def deploy_fund_me():
    account = get_account()
    # Passing Price Feed to our Solidity contract.

    # If we are on a persistent network like rinkeby, use its price feed address.
    # Otherwise use Mocks.
    # print(account)
    if network.show_active() != "development":
        price_feed_address = config["networks"][network.show_active()][
            "eth_usd_price_feed"
        ]
    else:
        print(f"The current Network is: {network.show_active()}")
        print("Deploying Mock....")
        mock_aggregator = MockV3Aggregator.deploy(
            18, 2000000000000000000, {"from": accounts}
        )
        price_feed_address = mock_aggregator.address
        print("Mock Deployed!!")

    fund_me = FundMe.deploy(
        price_feed_address,
        {"from": account},
        publish_source=True,
    )
    print(f"It is deployed to {fund_me.address}")


def main():
    deploy_fund_me()
```

**And Here's the error Window::**

```
Running '\Users\HP\Development\demos\brownie_fund_me\scripts\deploy.py::main'...
The current Network is: development
Deploying Mock....
  File "c:\users\hp\development\demos\brownie_simple_storage\venv\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 50, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "c:\users\hp\development\demos\brownie_simple_storage\venv\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 103, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File "\Users\HP\Development\demos\brownie_fund_me\scripts\deploy.py", line 34, in main
    deploy_fund_me()
  File "\Users\HP\Development\demos\brownie_fund_me\scripts\deploy.py", line 19, in deploy_fund_me
    mock_aggregator = MockV3Aggregator.deploy(
  File "c:\users\hp\development\demos\brownie_simple_storage\venv\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py", line 528, in __call__
    return tx["from"].deploy(
AttributeError: 'Accounts' object has no attribute 'deploy'
Terminating local RPC client...
```

Everyone's Help would be appreciated.

**THANKS IN ADVANCE**

Comment: clearly fro0m the error message, the accounts class doesn't have a deploy method defined.  Can't be of further help without you posting the source code for accounts class.  Please include a clear concise question that includes a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") containing both data, and code that can be copied and pasted along with a clear description of what is wrong with your current effort.

Comment: Sometimes the smallest mistakes make us think too much. 
It would just be `"from": account` instead of **accounts**. While rechecking, I corrected that error......

Thanks for your concern!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution to your problem...use **account** instead of **accounts**

```py
from brownie import accounts, config, MyContract

def deploy_my_contract():
    account = accounts[0]
    my_contract = MyContract.deploy({"from": account})
    some_return_value = my_contract.some_func()
    print(some_return_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing the same course..
My problem was that accounts[0] was in a function and not returning anything due to missing () in the call

This is now working for me.

```
def get_account():
    if network.show_active == "development":
        return accounts[0]
    else:
    return accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])

def deploy_fund_me():
    account = get_account()
    fund_me = FundMe.deploy({"from": account})
```